# How to decrypt an encrypted data in c# by using RSACryptoServiceProvider() in ubuntu?

Tags: c#, encryption, mono, cryptography, rsa

I am encrypting my data by using `RSACryptoServiceProvider()` class in c#. I want to decrypt the data in ubuntu, that was encrypted in c#. Can you suggest me which mechanism I need to follow in order to decrypt. Following function is for encryption:

```
public static void Encrypt(String PublicKey, String plainText, out String cipherText)
{
    try
    {             
        int dwKeySize = 1024;
        // TODO: Add Proper Exception Handlers
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCryptoServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(dwKeySize);
        rsaCryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString(PublicKey);
        int keySize = dwKeySize / 8;
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(plainText);
        // The hash function in use by the .NET RSACryptoServiceProvider here is SHA1
        // int maxLength = ( keySize ) - 2 - ( 2 * SHA1.Create().ComputeHash( rawBytes ).Length );
        int maxLength = keySize - 42;
        int dataLength = bytes.Length;
        int iterations = dataLength / maxLength;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i <= iterations; i++)
        {
            byte[] tempBytes = new byte[(dataLength - maxLength * i > maxLength) ? maxLength : dataLength - maxLength * i];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, maxLength * i, tempBytes, 0, tempBytes.Length);
            byte[] encryptedBytes = rsaCryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt(tempBytes, true);
            // Be aware the RSACryptoServiceProvider reverses the order 
            // of encrypted bytes after encryption and before decryption.
            // If you do not require compatibility with Microsoft Cryptographic API
            // (CAPI) and/or other vendors.
            // Comment out the next line and the corresponding one in the 
            // DecryptString function.
            Array.Reverse(encryptedBytes);
            // Why convert to base 64?
            // Because it is the largest power-of-two base printable using only ASCII characters
            stringBuilder.Append(Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes));
        }
        cipherText = stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        cipherText = "ERROR_STRING";
        Console.WriteLine("Exception in RSA Encrypt: " + e.Message);
        //throw new Exception("Exception occured while RSA Encryption" + e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thought about using Mono on your Ubuntu installation and create an equivalent Decrypt method in C# as well?

Comment: What's the actual question here?

Comment: Is there a reason why you use RSA to encrypt multiple blocks? It's slow as hell and has some sweet attacks...

Answer (score 1):

Don't use RSA like that. It's not meant to be used that way and it's way too slow.

The *right* way is to use a symmetric algorithm, e.g. AES, and encrypt the key you used with RSA. See my [old blog entry](http://pages.infinit.net/ctech/20031101-0151.html) for C# code doing just that.

Answer (score 0):

You need the same mechanisms, but in reverse. Try first, ask later.